# iOS - How to add two rows of switches to a UITableView programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I am an iOS development newbie. I am trying to add two switches to a table programmatically using the following code -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
if(indexPath.section== 0){

    fooddrinkSettingSwitch=[[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];


    [fooddrinkSettingSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(preferenceSettingAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell addSubview:fooddrinkSettingSwitch];
    cell.accessoryView = fooddrinkSettingSwitch;

    apparelSettingSwitch=[[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];


    [apparelSettingSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(preferenceSettingAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell addSubview:apparelSettingSwitch];
    cell.accessoryView = apparelSettingSwitch;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;    
}


//get the dictionary object
NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"SettingTitle"];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
}
```

However, it displays Food & Drink as a switch and Apparel as a link. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your approach is that a `UITableViewCell` can have only one `accessoryView`. You probably want to make a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` to achieve what you're after.

Comment: @Suchi See: [`UITableViewCell` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewCell) and [a tutorial on making a custom `UITableViewCell`](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)